# Typescript: Unexpected token import

Tags: node.js, typescript

Just started working with typescript. Unfortunately when I try to build for production it fails.

Firstly I run

`tsc`

This passes without any error, but when I try to run the build file I get import errors

`node build/index.js`

The error I get is below:

```
[0] (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import {
[0]                                                               ^^^^^^
[0]
[0] SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
[0]     at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
[0]     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
```

Below is my tsconfig

```
{
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ],
   "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "es5",
            "es6",
        ],
        "pretty": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "./build",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "sourceMap": true
   }
}
```

I am using node `v8.9.3`

Comment: make `target` to `es6`

Comment: @gokcand it is the same issue when I set target to es6

Comment: I have just realised that the issue is with typeorm

Answer (score 11):

If you use TypeORM there can be a problem with your ormconfig. Your configuration file probably contains path like `src/entities/*.ts` in the `entity` section. So it causes requiring `*.ts` files from your `src` folder, not from `dist` folder.

Answer (score 5):

When working with NodeJs, your `tsconfig.json` should look like this:

```
{
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ],
   "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["es6"],        // No need for "es5" if you have "es6"
        "types": ["node"],      // When you code for nodejs
        "target": "es6",       // NodeJs v8.9.3 supports most of the es6 features
        "pretty": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "./build",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "sourceMap": true
   }
}
```